# Finding the common ratio without radical formulas

Tags: sequences-and-series

The first term of a geometric series is $2000.$ The sum of the first four terms is $5468.75.$ It is known that all terms of the series are positive. What is the common ratio?

In a textbook, this problem was posed to students who have knowledge of factor/remainder theorem and the quadratic formula - they are not aware of the existence of a cubic formula. Furthermore, numerical methods and graph plotting are not acceptable solution methods since students are supposed to be preparing for a written exam.

From my own work under these restrictions, I have been able to show that this is equivalent to solving the cubic $$ 64r^{3} + 64r^{2} + 64r - 111 = 0 $$ I did this by using the known formula for the sum of the first $n$ terms, spotting that $r=1$ is a solution (but not *the* solution) and factoring it out.

The solution in the textbook tells us that $r=\frac{3}{4}$ is the solution, which certainly does work, but I am at a loss as to how someone could do this without the cubic formula or some other unfamiliar method.

Is there a different elementary way to solve this problem? Is it possible to proceed with the cubic under my restrictions?

Comment: I think you are a little bit too nervous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving your equation is quite simple: if $$a_n r^n + \dots + a_0 =0$$ and we are searching for *rational* roots of the form $\frac p q$ with $(p,q)=1$, then $q|a_n$ and $p|a_0$ (just replace $r$ by $\frac p q$ above and convince yourself). Now, we do not know if $r$ is rational indeed, but we may try our luck and hope that it be. Therefore, we should look for roots of the type $\frac p q$ with $p|111$ and $q|64$ (possibly with sign), and this gives reasonably few possibilities. It turns out that $p=3$ and $q=4$ does the job.

Comment: I plan to accept this answer shortly unless someone else can come up with something more rudimentary which would be feasible for our students with their current knowledge of mathematics.